# Where DHTML Menu link's title is getting printed

Tags: routes, navigation

I would like to replace the title attribute of DHTML menu's link with a javascript tool tip. But i could not find the place where the link attributes are printed. ie. where  test  is mentioned.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

By implementing [theme_menu_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7), you can adjust the menu links to whatever you need.